# I can't get the footer to stay on the bottom of the page.

Tags: html, css, footer

I can't seem to get the footer on my page to stay at the bottom and have it continually pushed down when ever I want to add more content. Now I know that this question has been asked about a million times, and I have read through many tutorials and watched several videos on the subject.

However, I just can't seem to make it work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The footer appears to only stay in one place. I know that to someone here, you're going to find an obvious mistake that is easily fixed. However, I'm not a professional web designer by any means. In fact, this is not my job at all. But I always like to learn how to do things, and my site looks amazing (At least to me). I just can't, for the life of me, figure out what's wrong with this one problem.

Should I start by pasting the entire coding for my page?

Comment: Don't post all the code, just the code relevant to your footer and what's going wrong, but yes, you should definitely post code, and even better, also post a jsFiddle.

Comment: I don't know what a jsFiddle is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a website that let you share your code with others and let them work with it easily

Comment: You can post your code on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ , and the have a link back to jsFiddle from here, that allows us to see and debug your code more directly.

Comment: A jsFiddle is an online tool that you can use to test your javascript code. The site is: https://jsfiddle.net/  You put your javascript code in there and then runs it. The you can change it on the fly to see the expected results.

Comment: Ok, so, I think this is what you want, right?

https://jsfiddle.net/fsbw2m2q/

I think I got everything that you asked for, including the HTML and CSS.

Comment: Edit the question so everybody can see the link easily! Anyway, i suggest you to read this guide, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ when i was at the beginning it helped me a lot and it might help you too! There are many guides like that, if you google "Sticky footer" you'll find many different techniques!

Comment: How should I edit the question, Mattia Nocerino?

I have read many tutorials and even watched videos. I have to say, it is all very confusing to me sometimes. But I have used tutorials that just say to copy and paste the code onto my site, which I've done, and I've even tried changing some numbers around to see if it would do anything. I am baffled by how it knows to stay where it is now and not go further down when I add more content.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/godfrzero/g5qnq3vf/), hopefully I didn't misunderstand your question. The JS in there can be ignored, only the CSS and HTML are relevant.

I've seen a lot of people asking this question, and I had it too at one point, so I figured I'd post a comprehensive answer here :) Anyway, explanation:

The HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button id="add-content">Add more content</button>
    <ul class="content">
        <li>I am content, destroyer of worlds</li>
        <li>I am content, destroyer of worlds</li>
        <li>I am content, destroyer of worlds</li>
        <li>I am content, destroyer of worlds</li>
        <li>I am content, destroyer of worlds</li>
    </ul>
    <footer>
        Footer!
    </footer>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body,
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

So, the content & footer have a wrapper around them, because that's how most people roll, but it's not required and you can actually do this using just the `body` as the wrapper.

Now, key points to note:

- `html, body` has a `height: 100%`: The height of a block element is, by default, determined by it's content. So, even if you try to position the footer at the bottom, using `position: absolute; bottom: 0`, it's actually getting pushed to the bottom of the **first non-static parent element**, or if there are no non-static parent elements, the bottom of the `html/body` element. By setting `height: 100%`, we can force the `body, html` elements to take up the entire available viewport and ignore content height. (You can also use `min-height: 100%;`, but it depends on which browsers you want to support)
- `.wrapper` has a `min-height: 100%`: Between the sticky element and the element you want to sticky the footer to, you want to make sure all elements have 100% height, otherwise they'll collapse to match the height of the content.
- `.wrapper` has `box-sizing: border-box; padding-bottom: 100px;`: The padding at the bottom is to make sure that if content gets added to the wrapper, it doesn't end up getting lost *behind* the sticky footer. This padding should match the footer height, or be greater.
- `footer` has `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`: No explanation needed here, I'm guessing. The next point is actually more important.
- `.wrapper` has `position: relative`: Remember what I said about **non-static parents**? By making `.wrapper` non-static, we make sure that `footer` stays *inside* `.wrapper`, while remaining sticky.

I think that covers it, but I'd recommend playing around with the relevant HTML/CSS in the fiddle to get a clear understanding of what's going on and how the elements interact.

**P.S.**: While going through your fiddle, I noticed there's a `.wrapper` class, but no element? I'd recommend adding that to the fiddle(and removing footer *content*), it'll be easier to track down what's missing :)

**P.P.S.**: Check out [this fiddle branched from yours](https://jsfiddle.net/godfrzero/fsbw2m2q/5/), I've made the following modifications after removing all unnecessary HTML content:

- Added .wrapper element around all the body content, except the footer.
- Added .push element at the bottom of the .wrapper element
- Removed a bunch of unnecessary CSS styles from the footer, changed positioning to relative.

Comment: Oh brother...

Ok, I'm really lost. I am trying to understand it all, and I'm only kind of getting it. If I post the entirety of my page template's coding, could you look at it, see what's wrong and make the necessary changes? It's not a big page, but I need to see where exactly things need to go or be changed. I have been trying to fix this all day and It's just not working. I saw your fiddle, and it looks like it works beautifully, but I don't know how to implement it into my page.

Comment: @Levant It'll be enough if you update your fiddle, I'm going through it right trying to track the problem down.

Comment: @Levant Basically, add the `.push`, `.wrapper` elements into the fiddle, remove all the content inside the footer and associated CSS code. That should reduce the amount of code we have to go through to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I have no idea about what I'm doing. I just noticed your "PS" about a wrapper with no element. Yeah, I don't know. Probably leftover code from my many attempts at rectifying the situation. I have absolute zero background in web design other than what I have designed myself. I am trying to replace my old page with this new one that I'm building, and I just need this footer problem to be solved I pick up things here and there, but I'm not very coherent in html or anything of the sort. Here is the entire site fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fsbw2m2q/1/

Again, sorry.

Comment: @Levant I've updated the answer with a P.P.S. that should solve your problem. I'm leaving the rest of it as reference for anyone else looking for sticky footer help.

Comment: Godfrzero, I really do appreciate all of your help... but I honestly have no idea what I am doing wrong still. I am trying to follow what you wrote in the fiddle, but absolutely nothing changes.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy... Someone please just take the fiddle that I have posted that has the entirety of my page template, and make the necessary changes to make this work. I have done absolutely nothing all day, as well as most of this week, other then trying to fix this, and I can't. I'm trying to follow all of the examples that I am seeing, and it's just not working out for me. I have to be doing something wrong. If I can physically see what changes are made on the template itself, I can understand it better, and I can copy it and finally get somewhere on my site.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with:

```
    .myStyle{
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
   }
```

If you want the footer to always be visible on the page (even when you scroll) you need to use: `position:fixed;`

Comment: I'm actually looking to have the footer get pushed down when I add content, as in not always on the bottom of the window, but rather always at the bottom of the page. I have copied and pasted code regarding this from other tutorials, but it does not seem to work. I know that the error is on my part, though.

Answer (score 0):

Haa the famous sticky footer problem. I think we all once passed by their.
If you do as it says there > http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ You'll manage to do one proper.

The other solution is to have a `position:fixed; bottom:0px;` see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gm0j2os/) but this will mean your footer will be always display over content. It will be position relatively to your window and not to your page.

Comment: I don't want a fixed position footer. I want one that is always at the bottom of the page (Not window), and gets pushed down to the bottom automatically when I add new content to the page.

Comment: The Ryan Fait method is  actually what I am using already. I don't know why it isn't working.